# Analytic continuation for PI(1+z^(4^n))

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-continuation

How to do analytic continuation for following function?
$$f(z) = \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty} {(1+z^{4^n})}$$
Evidently it satisfies $f(z)f(z^2)=\dfrac{1}{1-z}$...

Comment: Analytic continuation to where? The function seems to have a natural boundary at the unit circle...

Comment: Oh.. It seems that you're right.

Comment: Notice that the function has zeros at all the $4^k$th roots of unity -- a dense set.

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't think that is a very convincing argument -- what about the function $\prod_{n\geq 0} (1+z^{2^n}) = \frac1{1-z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers above are absolutely fine. Just to give a completely obvious argument:

Take a the line $z=t\exp(i\phi)$ with $\phi=2\pi/{4^{n_0}}$ for some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$.
Then 
$$
f(z)=\Pi_{n=0}^{n_0-1}\left(1+t^{4^n}\exp\left(i\phi^{4^n}\right)\right)\Pi_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(1+t^{4^n}) 
$$
Since $4^{n_0}/2\neq 4^{n^\prime}$, $\Pi_{n=0}^{n_0-1}\left(1+\exp\left(i\phi^{4^n}\right)\right)\neq0$, and therefore $f$ diverges at $t=1$.

So your analytic extension would have an accumulation of essential singular points, on the sequence
$$
\left\{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4^n}\right),1\right\},
$$ 
and that's not very popular in the analytic community.

Answer (score 9):

It was conjectured by G. Pólya in 1916 and proved by F. Carlson in 1921 that a 
power series with integer coefficients and radius of convergence one is either 
rational or has the unit circle as a natural boundary. Since $f(z)$ is clearly 
not rational, the second alternative must hold.

Comment: Could you please give more details about this? I'm just puzzled..

Comment: See *George Pólya, Collected Papers*, MIT Press, 1974, pp. 192-198 and 779-780 for information on Carlson's theorem. $f(z)$ is not rational because, for instance, it has arbitrarily long strings of 0 coefficients.